# What kind of MySQL join do I need?

Tags: mysql, outer-join

Simple MySQL tables with matching ID values across tables:

```
table 1;
pid, firstname

table 2;
id, pid, property, value
```

Lets say there is one person entry in table 1:

```
pid: 1
firstname: fred
```

For each person there are multiple table 2 entries:

```
pid: 1
property: likes cats?
value: no

pid: 1
property: eye colour
value: orange

pid: 1
property: favourite food
value: sox
```

I want to select just two of the many table two entries, say the eye colour and favour food entries for a given person ID. What kind of outer join can achieve this?

```
SELECT `t1`.name
FROM `table1` AS t1
LEFT JOIN `table2` t2 ON `t1`.pid = `t2`.pid
WHERE `t1`.pid = 1
AND `t2`.property =  'eye colour'
```

I'm stuck here, how to get two rows from table2 and include favour food also? (Before anyone says it, no I can't change the structure of this database).

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What does this query output ?

Comment: What you are trying to do is "pivoting an entity-attribute-value table".

Comment: Yeah, everyone knows that, isn't that obvious ;P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like:

```
 SELECT t1.name, t2.property, t2.value
 FROM table2 t2
 INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.pid = t2.pid
 WHERE t2.pid = 1
 AND t2.property IN ('eye colour','favourite food')
```

Or you just wanted the first two however MySQL indexed it:

```
 SELECT t1.name, t2.property, t2.value
 FROM table2 t2
 INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.pid = t2.pid
 WHERE t2.pid = 1
 LIMIT 2
```

There's no real reason to use a LEFT JOIN here, since there should always be an associated `pid` defined in `table1`.

Comment: I love your first answer, IN, this is good stuff! :) Also yes, it should be an INNER JOIN here. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You need to left join twice:

```
SELECT 
  t1.name
  ,t2a.value as eye_color
  ,t2b.value as fav_food
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2a ON (t1.pid = t2a.pid AND t2a.property = 'eye colour')
LEFT JOIN table2 t2b ON (t1.pid = t2b.pid AND t2b.property = 'fav food')
WHERE t1.pid = 1
```

Comment: +1. I'm just curious why you decided to join the table twice instead of using an OR?

Comment: @Ben, because I'm pivoting the table. If I just use an `or` then I'll have multiple lines per pid, now I have only one line per pid.

Comment: This is a really great method. I can see how this would be advantageous in almost another other situation, but for this instance I need 'Crontabs' answer, otherwise this is a great answer, thanks!

Comment: @javano np, you did say you wanted 2 rows per `pid`.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
SELECT t.name, t.value, t3.value
FROM
(SELECT t1.name, t2.value, t1.pid
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.pid = t2.pid
WHERE t1.pid = 1
AND t2.property =  'eye colour') t
LEFT JOIN table2 t3 ON t.pid = t3.pid
WHERE t.pid = 1
AND t3.property =  'favourite food'
```

This will also work for people who don't have an 'eye colour' or 'favourite food' entry

Comment: You've got syntax errors in your query, the general idea is correct though. The correct order of the clauses is: SELECT - FROM - JOIN - WHERE ..... **not: (select-from-join-where-join-where)** And you cannot have spaces in alias identifiers.

Comment: @Johan Got rid of the special chars. Thanks!

Comment: Amit, that was the `only` part that was correct (although not really necessary)

Comment: @Johan Third time's the charm!

Comment: Nope: All the errors I pointed out are still there. You cannot have a `join` after a `where` and alias names with spaces are not allowed.

Comment: +1 That will work, but compare your query to my answer both output the same data, which one would you prefer?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do this with one query then you should use INNER JOIN but i'm not recommending this. If i were you i would select first the person then i would create another query to recieve the necessary table2 entries. Try both of my solutions you could choose the right one for you.